# No option to recover password in Lenovo Tab S8 (S8-50)

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, password, locked-out

So I locked myself out of my tab and I can only open it by entering the password (which I forgot). There is no forgot password option where you can enter your google account to get pass the lock screen. The phone has a google account. Is there any way to bring up that menu? I thought all android devices had the *Forgot Password?* option

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! I've just added the `locked-out` tag to your question. Please start with [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info), which holds some first-aid and links to helpful posts. Then come back and either [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) (when solved), or [edit] it with what you've tried and where you're stuck. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem too. My solution was to connect it to the computer and did factory reset. ***If you have root than follow instruction on this link:***  [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVJ7T2oC_Zs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVJ7T2oC_Zs**)
***ON SOME DEVICES IT WORKS EVEN WITHOUT ROOT ACCESS***

Good luck! - Nik